# SemanticUI Button still active after clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, semantic-ui

```
import React from 'react'
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const ButtonExampleShorthand = () => <Button content='Click Here' />

export default ButtonExampleShorthand
```

When you click on the button, it becomes gray and stays so unless you click somewhere else. Is it possible to make it return to the initial state(light gray) right after you clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any `<button>` (not just ones from Semantic-UI) has a number of different states it can be in. These states can be selected and styled with [pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) in CSS.

`:hover` is when you move your mouse over the button

`:active` is when you have clicked down on the button but not yet released your click.

`:focus` is when a user has used the `tab` key to focus their browser on that element.

The issue you refer to in your question arises because **clicking on a button sets the browser's focus on that button**. This focus remains after you release your click and move your mouse off of the button.

If the styles for your button are the same for `:active` and for `:focus` it will appear as if the button is still clicked (but really the button just has the browser's focus which is affecting the styling). Clicking elsewhere on the page removes the browser's focus from the button and therefore updates the styling.

A **NOT** recommended solution is to just have the `:focus` styling match the styling when the button is not active, hovered, or focused. But, this is discouraged because assistive technologies rely on focus to work correctly. If no styling changes occur with `:focus` a keyboard-only user will not be able to utilize your site.

In React, you'll need to utilize createRef (or useRef for functional components) to manage focus around a button. The Semantic-UI-react docs have [an example that will be helpful](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/#usage-focus). Note that the behavior you are describing also occurs with their example button. The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html#programmatically-managing-focus) also have some clear explanations of the ideas around this issue.

To better understand focus, hover, and active, I recommend [this post](https://bitsofco.de/when-do-the-hover-focus-and-active-pseudo-classes-apply/#:%7E:text=%3Ahover%20%2C%20%3Afocus%20%2C%20and%20%3Aactive%20are%20pseudo%2D,button%20or%20an%20input%20field.) which has excellent interactive examples that clarify the different states and how they interact.

It's also worth pointing out that Firefox, Chrome (and likely other browsers with developer features) have a tool where you can toggle/test the states of elements.

[This (beautifully Photoshopped) screengrab shows you where to find that feature in Firefox. It's in a similar location in Chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbTCx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's `Button`'s focus state, I suggest you keep a focus state on you buttons but here's how you can override that style.

Add this in your CSS file:

```css
.ui.button:focus: {
  background-color: #e0e1e2 none;
}
```

Comment: -1 for the reasons stated by Tyler. Additionally, overriding the buttons with a specific color like that can have interactions if you wish to later use other SemanticUI button styling (active, primary, basic).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a `CustomButton`. Don't know if that's the most efficient solution.

```
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { useRef } from 'react'

const CustomButton = ({children, ...props}) => {
  const { onClick } = props 
  const buttonRef = useRef()
  const handleOnClick = ({...props}) => {
    buttonRef.current.ref.current.blur()
    if (onClick) {
      onClick(props)
    }
  }
  return (
    <Button {...props} ref={buttonRef} onClick={handleOnClick}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  )
}

export default CustomButton
```